Error occur in use icon from ant-design/icons
ERROR  Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component path must be a function (received undefined). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.[enter image description here](https://i.sstat[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/TYmGE2Jj.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/pWhSIXfg.png)ic.net/3KI2kF5l.png)
use icon in tab menu for my react native app
